# 'Cannot implicitly convert ...TEnum to ... System.Enum'

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have a class with the following in it:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<Enum, string>> Items { get; set; }
```

and I'm trying to assign an existing `List<KeyValuePair<TEnum, string>>` to it but I'm receiving

> Cannot implicitly convert TEnum to System.Enum.

How do I define the Items variable to have a TEnum as the key? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: what is `TEnum`? Looks like a generic param but you've not supplied enough code to be able to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `TEnum` is a generic of your class, simply use it:

```
public class Whatever<TEnum>
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<TEnum, string>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

btw: Unfortunately you can't place enum constraints on generics so you can't be sure `TEnum` is an `Enum`

```
//Not possible
public class Whatever<TEnum> where TEnum : Enum
```

Comment: Ah! I hadn't realised I'd forgotten to add <TEnum> to my class definition, thank you!